# Ember js find by properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Can't find records from my model

Ember version:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.0.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.2 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.0.0 ember.js
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.9.1 ember.js
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Model:

```
App.Concert = DS.Model.extend({
    tour_id: DS.attr(),
    tickets: DS.attr()
});
```

Finding:

```
this.get("store").find("concert", {tour_id: 1}).then(function(result) {
            console.log("--------------");
            console.log(result.content.length);
            console.log("--------------");
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("broken");
        });
```

Console:

```
------------- 
length: 0 
--------------
```

I can't find records from my model by properties. Anybody can help?
I know what records with tour_id: 1 exist

Answer (score 1):

Edu is actually partially correct (see below), but the real reason that you don't get back any records is most likely the format that your API returns. Ember Data is very strict about the type of data it expects and how it is structured. If you query your API for concerts with a `tour_id` of `1`, then this is how the response should look like. Notice that the root object is the pluralized model name and the key is an array of concerts.

```
{
  "concerts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "tour_id": 1,
      "name": "cool concert"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "tour_id": 1,
      "name": "awesome concert"
    }
  ]
}
```

Regarding Edu's comment, if you invoke the store's `find` method, Ember Data doesn't perform a regular find. Under the hood, `findQuery` is invoked and it returns an instance of [`DS.RecordArray`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html). This isn't a regular JavaScript array so you need to respect how Ember works and how it deals with arrays.

I recommend reading up on [`DS.RecordArray`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RecordArray.html) in the Ember guides. Also, if you plan on using Ember Data, you shouldn't be scared by the idea of exploring its source. Ember Data is a ambitious project and the documentation is still very much a work in progress. Ember Data's source is therefore your most important source of information.

Answer (score 0):

try using getters...

```
console.log(result.get('length'));
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?